# Помогите составить SQL запрос c извлечением нескольких параметров

Tags: php, sql

Есть следующий php код

```
$INSERT_USERS = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='".$id_add_user[0]."'");
```

Цель: составить запрос, что то типо:

```
$id_add_user[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна последовательность id тогда:

`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id < {count($id_add_user)}`

Для выборочных чисел:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ";
foreach($el in $id_add_user)
{
   $sql+= "id={el} || ";
}

$sql = substr($sql,0,-4);
```

Comment: Мне из массива $id_add_user нужно, так как он доставляет параметры из другого SQL запроса

Comment: в случаи последовательности просто число элементов подставляешь..
иначе нужно делать перебор массива и составлять длинную строку для каждого числа.. ну или делать запрос для каждого числа - не рекомендую

Comment: Последовательность Имеете ввиду что то типо $INSERT_USERS = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='".$id_add_user[0]."||".$id_add_user[0]."'  "); ???

Comment: идут все подряд... 0-5 - тут 6 чисел и можно подставить просто число всех элементов. Иначе ...допилю в ответ

Comment: Можно как то без foreach ???

Comment: это для случая чисел с из случайніыми айдишниками.. тебе их с массива или ручками вписывать в запрос(нужно знать сколько таких айдишников в массиве прийдет) и писать как ты выше написал.. или когда неизвестно количество элементов в массиве - перебор в цикле.

Comment: А разве так нельзя сделать ? $INSERT_USERS = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id ='".$id_add_user[0]."' OR  id ='".$id_add_user[1]."'");

Comment: $id_add_user[value 1-10]  value является константой у меня

Comment: можно.. но для большого массива много кода будет

Comment: Как то сложновато. уж лучше (хотя конечно это не лучше, потому как подставлять сами значения в запрос вообще нельзя, иначе возможны sql-инъекции): `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN(". implode(',', $id_add_user) . ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, нёл решение проблемы

```
$INSERT_USERS = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id ='".implode(",",$id_add_user)."' ");
```